# Google Calendar - Get events not reacting on parameters

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I've a script where I try to get all upcoming events from a Google Calendar.
Regarding to the API documentation, I have used "timeMin" for this, but it still gives me results in the past.

Have Google changed anything about this and if yes, what is the new way to do this?

My code is:

```
                $calendarId = 'primary';
                $optParams = array(
                    'maxResults' => 100,
                    'timeMin' => ''.date("Y-m-d",time()).'T00:00:00-00:00'
                );
                

                try{

                    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary',$optParams);

                }catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                }
```

Comment: How much earlier? Do you have your timezone set correctly?

Comment: Bookings from 2020 is also a part of the return, so should not be anything about timezone or something like that

Comment: Can you give an example request/response?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of an event that should be retrieved by your query but is not?

Comment: The problem is, that Google is just randomly taking events. It is not sorted by event date and doesn't react on "timeMin" parameter. If I say that it should only show bookings larger than 2021-09-05, it would still show bookings from 2020

Comment: Can you clarify what URL you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue. The `timeMin` parameter is being observed by the API. I don't get events that are before `timeMin`.